# Finding old Google Forms edit links

Tags: google-forms

How do I find old Google Forms edit links for which I don't have the direct URL any more?

I have submitted a few forms recently where I didn't bother to take note of the edit URL. Now I want to check what I wrote on those forms, so I was wondering if there might be a list of forms that I have submitted somewhere.

I have tried looking in the obvious places (Google Drive, Gmail and Google Forms itself) but so far come up short. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to do it?

Since I'm not the creator of these forms, [answers on this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/50009/10108) are no help to me.

Comment: So these are forms for which you've submitted data?

Comment: A simple slip of the finger. You could have just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have edit access to the forms they could be found using Google Drive. When they are edited recently, the easier way could be the Recent view. You could found them using the [Shared with me](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375057?hl=en) view and by [searching](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?hl=en).

Also you could check the activity panel, look at the Trash and search for orphan files (files without a folder). For details see [Find or recover a file](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/1716222?hl=en)

Another way to find the forms edit links, as well as any other web page links, is to check your browser history.