# Show URL used to edit responses from a Google Form in a Google Spreadsheet by using a script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to make the edit URL for a Google Form automatically populate in the response Google Sheet that it's attached to. I've seen [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50009/is-there-a-way-to-keep-track-of-the-url-used-to-edit-responses-in-google-form) already and want to use it, but I'm having issues trying to figure out where exactly to put the script.

I've tried putting it in the script editor in the Google Spreadsheet that I would like the URL to appear in, but I'm not sure where to go from there. In the script editor I've tried to test it as an add-on but that didn't end up working.

I have little experience with scripts and the script editor in Google Sheets. As a final note I am using one other add-on called AutoCrat in the same Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: Besides the link to the source of the code that you tried it good to include the code and the steps followed to do your tests.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Short answer

The [link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50009/is-there-a-way-to-keep-track-of-the-url-used-to-edit-responses-in-google-form) points to a Q&A that has two answers but non-of them looks to me to be appropiate. I.E. the code of one of answers is incomplete and both of them send emails, so the adoption is too complex to be used as a starting point.

Below is a script that is easier to adopt.

## Instructions

1. Create a test form and note the **form ID** (between `../d/` and `/edit` in the url).
   [image: New form]
2. Set the form to send responses to a new spreadsheet.
   [image: Connect a spreadsheet]
3. You'll be redirected to the new spreadsheet. Note the active **sheet name** (rename it if you want) and add a **header** to the column to be used to hold the response edit URLs, i.e. `Edit Url`. NOTE: Capitalization is very important, so be very careful on how do you write it.
   [image: Responses spreadsheet]
4. Go to `Tools > Script editor` to add a Google Apps Script project bounded to the spreadsheet.
   [image: Spreadsheet scripts]
5. Replace the default code with the code below (remember to edit the global variables according to your case).
   [image: Script code]
6. Save the project, and then add an installable form summit trigger (if you get an "Authorization required" dialog, click "Review Permissions" and then "Allow").
   [image: Form submit trigger]
7. Submit some sample responses to test the solution.

## Code

```
/*
 * Global Variables
 */

// Form URL
var formURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/form-id/viewform';
// Sheet name used as destination of the form responses
var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';
/*
 * Name of the column to be used to hold the response edit URLs 
 * It should match exactly the header of the related column, 
 * otherwise it will do nothing.
 */
var columnName = 'Edit Url' ;
// Responses starting row
var startRow = 2;

function getEditResponseUrls(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(columnName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
  for(var i = startRow-1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex] == '') {
      var timestamp = data[i][0];
      var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
      if(formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;
      var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
      sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+1).setValue(editResponseUrl);
    }
  }
}
```

## Additional resources

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/rubenrivera/4ed2110cda3fbdbc29d2d2d3a4af29c0) with the content from the question and answer. this b/c I'm exploring ways to better collaborate between end-users who write code.

Comment: I got it, it was the sheet name, and I took out '/viewform' at the end of the URL. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Rubén - I took the liberty of adding a little more detail to your great tutorial, as I struggled with a few of the steps when I followed it myself.

Comment: I "accepted" the changes to the instructions but not to the code but i created a gist. I'm wondering if this could help  us to better communicate regarding code changes suggestions / code variants.

Comment: Ok. The main reason I changed the code was to show that you can use `FormApp.openById()` with only the form ID instead of `FormApp.openByUrl()` with the whole URL, in case Google's URL format changes in the future. I'll leave a comment on your gist instead.

Comment: The best answer example now doesn't match the attached code. Be sure to use the edit URL not the viewform URL.
This error resulted when I used the Viewform URL instead of the edit URL.
"No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it."

Comment: In my google script window, the "Current project's triggers" was under "Edit".

Comment: Works even with already existing responses! I've got an existing form and spreadsheet with some responses already filled (the "Allow users to edit responses after submitted" option was selected from the start). Right after a new submission all of the rows/responses got filled with their edit link (which worked even for old responses). I've used the the code by Sphinxxxx@gist

Comment: @Rubén: how to check if a form allow response edit? I can see the function Set here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setallowresponseeditsenabled. But there is no Get function

Comment: @HoangTrinh See [canEditResponse()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#caneditresponse)