# Brainstorm Phase - Daily Turnover: Submit and retrieve using Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'm working on moving from an awful Excel document to a Google Sheet where employees can type in notes on a "Form" and have it record the data as a "record".

[image]____________ [image]

When the user opens the document, I would like the datepicker validated cell A1 to default to today and the cell B2 to populate with the note corresponding to that date on the "Records" sheet.  Easy enough.

The tough part is I'd like to be able to have the user change data and save it to the records sheet.

Is this outside of Google Sheets?  I was looking at Google Forms but that just seems awful to try and customize and work with.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

To edit the form responses you need the edit response URL. As a form owner, the usual way to get them is by using a script.

## Explanation

Google Forms has a setting to allow respondents to edit their answers but it's not recorded anywhere. The good news is that by using Google Apps Script you could list all the edit response links next to the responses. Please take a look to the related question linked in the references section.

## References

- [Show URL used to edit responses from a Google Form in a Google Spreadsheet by using a script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89551/show-url-used-to-edit-responses-from-a-google-form-in-a-google-spreadsheet-by-us)