# Google form reference number

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Once clicking on Submit - can each person be given a reference number? Refernce number must be included in the spreadsheet. Each person needs to make payment and we need them to use their reference number so that we can allocate the payments received correctly.

Comment: The best you cold so is use one of the confirmation email add-ons or custom coded scripts to send an email and provide the reference number either via an additional column in the spreadsheet or the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Each Google Form submission has a timestamp. You could use it as the reference number. Another value that you could use is the link to edit the response. For further details see [Show URL used to edit responses from a Google Form in a Google Spreadsheet by using a script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89551/show-url-used-to-edit-responses-from-a-google-form-in-a-google-spreadsheet-by-us)

Comment: isn't there a risk in using a value that could be similar for 2 or more individuals?