# Use Google Forms to allow updating of old data and linking to correct record

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I organise a small holiday programme which requires quite a bit of information about the children who attend (to ensure they are safe). This information splits into two types:

- Information that never or rarely changes: Child's Name, Date of birth, Home Address
- Information which changes with each enrolment: Days attending, Child's Interests

At the moment, we use a paper form for the first set of information, and a google form for the second set. I would like to move to using (two?) Google Forms for all the information.

With the "rarely changes" information, I want to be able to display what we already know, and allow the parent to make updates as necessary. For example, if your address has changed, you want to change address but not have to re-enter every other piece of information.

Please can you help me:

- Read the information from the Google Sheet for the new form
- Create a link from the original form to the appropriate record on the new form.

This programme is run by a small charity and we need to solve this problem in a cost effective way. Cutting down on physical paper will save us time and printing costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Read the information from the Google Sheet for the new form

Google Forms doesn't include a built-in feature to "read" the information from a Google Sheet but you could use a Google Sheets / Forms add-ons or Google Apps Script to add the Google Sheets data to a Google Form.

You should search the Google Sheets / Forms add-ons store to look for an add-on that fits your needs or to write a script by yourself or hire a programmer. Alternatively you could post a question on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) to ask for an add-on recommendation.

**Related**

- [Use add-ons and Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)

> Create a link from the original form to the appropriate record on the new form.

Google Forms only include "edit response URLs" to open a previously submitted response answers which allow to make changes to the answers and submit the response again. This edit response URLs are shown to respondent after a response is submitted and it's possible to get this URLs by using an add-on and/or Google Apps Script.

**Related**

- [Show URL used to edit responses from a Google Form in a Google Spreadsheet by using a script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/89551/88163)