# How do I get Google forms edit url to work

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

**I want to generate an edit url link in the google sheet for a google form which is linked to it.**

There are already instructions on how to do it. However they do not work for me.

I have followed the instructions from Ruben and Sphinxx yet I am still unable to get it to work.

There instructions are below in this link

[Show URL used to edit responses from a Google Form in a Google Spreadsheet by using a script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89551/show-url-used-to-edit-responses-from-a-google-form-in-a-google-spreadsheet-by-us/89566)

and

Sphinxx instruction below on gist

https://gist.github.com/rubenrivera/4ed2110cda3fbdbc29d2d2d3a4af29c0

**Steps taken**

1. I have used both methods from Sphinxx and Ruben with no luck.

   3 things I have to change in the code.

   - form link
   - sheet name
   - column name for location of edit url

   I have ensured no spelling mistakes. Paying particular attention to capitalisation. I have used both versions of the links.

   edit form id version
   https://docs.google.com/forms/d/example/edit

   view form link
   https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/example/viewform

   When using the edit form link I get no error messages however nothing happens in the sheet and no link is generated. When I use the view form link I get an error message.

   `No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 16, file "Code")`
2. I have ensured no spelling mistakes for the sheet name and also the column name where the link should appear
3. I get 0 errors when running the code and 0 errors for the trigger.
   I created the trigger in the sheet, to generate on form submission.

All of this and it does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Current Code for script in google sheets.**

using the edit url form id

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/example/edit

```
// Form
var formId = 'example';
// Sheet
var sheetName = 'Form Responses 1';
var columnName = 'Edit Url';

// Responses starting row
var startRow = 2;

function getEditResponseUrls(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
    var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(columnName);
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var form = FormApp.openById(formId);

for(var i = startRow-1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0] && !data[i][columnIndex]) {

        var timestamp = data[i][0];
        var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
        if(formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;

        var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
        sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+1).setValue(editResponseUrl);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is the sheet yours? (the sheet you want to create edit url for form)

Comment: yes the sheet and form are mine

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your code is not getting executed.

Please use the below function in the sheet. It will trigger when a new row is inserted into your sheet from the form. You have to insert your code into it.

```
function onFormSumbit(e) {
  var item = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,4).getValue();
  var email = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,17).getValue();

  var subject="New Item Code request"
  var message="A new material code for "+item+" has been requested. \n\nR&D head and Design head are requested to approve it by clicking Google Drive-New Erp Code and approve it by clicking the date column."
  //MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {cc:"xx@xx.com"});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However this does not work, I get the following error message. Also I do not want an email sent out. I just want the link to be put in the column.
TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 31, file "Code")

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that you have to execute this function on-form-submit. Use the "trigger" in the scripting page (with clock icon).  I had given you a working model which I am using. You can change the code to do anything you want using the variables (like putting the variable in a column etc)

Comment: @arulselvan Please add all the relevant details to the question it self. Comments by the post author are supposed to be used only to share transitional info.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code and it works perfectly. Make sure:

1. Edit form function is turned on
2. get the right form ID (the one you need to use is the URL of when you are creating the form itself **NOT VIEW MODE URL**)...I also made this mistake and it took me a while to figure out

   ```
   var formRes = FormApp.openById('XXXXXXXXX'); 
   var sheetRes = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('YYYYYYYY');
   var data = sheetRes.getDataRange().getValues();
   var urlCol = 10;
   var responses = formRes.getResponses();
   var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
   timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
   urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
   }
   for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
   resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);
   }
   sheetRes.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);
   ```